# Do I have a bad HD sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ntfs, testdisk

A computer user and an avid learner but an absolute novice to HD partition.

Got a new laptop less than a month but DAMNED, dropped it (tripped on the power cord and it dropped to the carpeted floor). the machine was streaming a movie when this happened.
I totally panicked so began searching for some disc scanning software to check the health of my HD (luckily screen was fine).

(apology for the lengthy intro)

I first ran HD Tune, which showed no damaged blocks (under quick scan), but 
when I ran testdisk, it showed

```
HPFS - NTFS          0     32   33     130   203   9     2099200 
HPFS - NTFS          0     32   33     130   203   9     2099200
HPFS - NTFS        130    203   10   89377    16  47  1433741312
check_FAT: Unusal media descritpor (0xf8! = 0xf0)
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 4 (FAT) != 255 (HD)
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 17 (FAT) != 63 (HD)
FAT12              2749     0    7    2750    74  18     20739 [NO NAME]
```

From what I found, the warning suggests "The warning about the disk are only warnings, not errors. They indicate that the disk geometry is different than the geometry information stored in FAT or NTFS boot sector."

No idea what disk geometry and geometry info in FAT/NTFS boot sector are. But is it safe to say the drop did not cause any damage to the HD sector ?????

Any other measure to take or software to run to know if the drop wrecks any damage to the HD. Any info sharing will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would be interesting to know whether the laptop has a feature to park the HDD when it detects acceleration fromo dropping it.

Comment: Don't think my HDD has such a feature (it's an HP, not Apple). But it'd be great to know how to add such a feature to the laptop, if feasible.

Comment: @BChen HP provides a similar feature called 3D DriveGuard. Not all laptop models support it, though. Before you do anything, make sure to **back up any important data**. When you're done, consider using the diagnostic tools provided by the disk manufacturer. Either way, those non-critical warnings are related to a FAT file system. I assume your operating system is Windows XP or later, so it's stored on a NTFS partition and those warning are unrelated. I also assume you have a single hard disk with just one partition containing both the OS and all your personal files; correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've never used HD Tune, so not sure what the numbers represent without a header title. You can, however, most likely ignore the FAT warning--It looks to me like that is a just a system recovery partition using a nonstandard partition type ID to "hide" it from Windows during normal computer operation. The only way to make sure your drive is good is to do a full surface scan.. but as said above, backup your data first.

Comment: Assuming your running windows you need to do a **chkdsk /r c:** from and administrative command prompt.  From there it will tell you that you need to reboot and do you want to do it now.  Say **YES** and manually restart the computer.  This may take several hours.

Comment: Even having done ^ may not guarantee anymore than `it works right now` - there may well be damage that will escalate with time and use.